# How to filter a django queryset using an array on a field like SQL's "IN"?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to filter a Django queryset using an array as a constraint on a field.  AKA, my array, for example, a set of primary keys.  I want to get only the objects that would be in that array, like the query in SQL would be:

```
SELECT * from table where id in [1,3,4,5,6....];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [django filter with list of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 4, 5, 6....])
```

Read more about it [at Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Comment: And a link to the queryset docs should help with many followup questions  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in