# How can I filter a Django query with a list of values?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm sure this is a trivial operation, but I can't figure out how it's done.

There's got to be something smarter than this:

```
ids = [1, 3, 6, 7, 9]

for id in ids:
    MyModel.objects.filter(pk=id)
```

I'm looking to get them all in one query with something like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=[1, 3, 6, 7, 9])
```

How can I filter a Django query with a list of values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter a django queryset using an array on a field like SQL's "IN"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016794/how-to-filter-a-django-queryset-using-an-array-on-a-field-like-sqls-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a django queryset using an array on a field like SQL's "IN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016794/how-to-filter-a-django-queryset-using-an-array-on-a-field-like-sqls-in)

Answer (score 832, accepted):

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut):

```
Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 7])
```

Comment: will it raise error if we pass empty list or return no record ?

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande No

Comment: @DylanYoung So it will return no record

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande Exactly.  Though,if you call `get()`, you will get an ObjectDoesNotExist error of course.

Comment: This will return a list, @Omoidashita's answer will return a dictionary of keys to objects.

Comment: and what if we have a double element list like 
 [('hello',1),('world',2),('hello',3),('hello',2)]
and we want to filter either having id 'hello' or  '2' or with both in a single query?

Answer (score 69):

When you have list of items and you want to check the possible values from the list then you can't use `=`.

The sql query will be like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ids=[1, 3, 6, 7, 9]` which is not true. You have to use `in` operator for this so you query will be like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ids in (1, 3, 6, 7, 9)` for that Django provide `__in` operator.

Comment: +1 for a small explanation. While I know I can read the docs, that doesn't necessarily mean I understood the docs.

Answer (score 16):

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk):

```
Blog.objects.in_bulk([1])
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>}

Blog.objects.in_bulk([1, 2])
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>, 2: <Blog: Cheddar Talk>}

Blog.objects.in_bulk([])
{}

Blog.objects.in_bulk()
{1: <Blog: Beatles Blog>, 2: <Blog: Cheddar Talk>, 3: <Blog: Django Weblog>}

Blog.objects.in_bulk(['beatles_blog'], field_name='slug')
{'beatles_blog': <Blog: Beatles Blog>}
```

Comment: This has an advantage over the accepted answer in some cases.  It returns a dictionary mapping the queried field to the object.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this.

```
Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 7])
```

But you should be careful. If just one element in the list is No-integer it doesn't work.
For example this is an Exception.

```
Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 'aa', 7])
```