# How to extract rows from the table, filter same column by diffrernt values?

Tags: django

I am working on `Django` Project with `Postgresql` database.

I have list of IDs i.e. Column values, I want to extract rows from the database.

Id list :

```
[238348, 238349, 238350, 1000]
```

(Id rang is not in sequence.)

For Single id value:

```
>>> page.objects.filter(id=238348)
[<page: o-0238348>]
```

I can use `for` loop to Iterate every ID and get row, but is there is any method like OR to extract rows?

**Edit:**
done

We can use `in`:

Demo:

```
>>> page.objects.filter(id__in=[238348,238349, 1])
[<page: o-0238349>, <page: o-0238348>]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [django filter with list of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in) field lookup:

```
page.objects.filter(id__in=[238348, 238349, 238350, 1000])
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed is `in` a solution, other way is using `Q`-objects. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects for documentation.

Comment: Yes, Thank You. It is working with `in`. I checked after posting question. +1

Comment: Yes, I saw when I posted my answer, but gave you another alternative, I thought `OR`s could be faster than `IN`, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause says `IN` is a bit faster (for MySQL), so disregard the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is work by `in`:

Demo:

```
>>> page.objects.filter(id__in=[238348,238349, 1])
[<page: o-0238349>, <page: o-0238348>]
```