# Django: filter for multiple arguments

Tags: python, django

Lets put we are using Django for your project and have a database table `Foo` with entries with Ids 1, 2 and 3.

Lets put we have a list `bar=[1,3]`

What would be the correct command to retrieve entries 1 and 3 based on `bar`?

Something like:

`Foo.objects.filter(id=bar)`?

or something like:

```
for item in bar:
  Foo.objects.get(id=item)
```

?

Comment: Sorry, my question is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values. I searched earlier but couldn't find correct words for it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
Foo.objects.filter(id__in=bar)
```

More information on [Django documentation: Queryset API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for help, too bad I didn't find this earlier at Django reference.