# Django 'dynamic' filtering

Tags: django, filter

I have a list , 
    l = ['XXX', 'YYY']

And I need filtred my model with this elements of list (number of this elements wouldn't be constant)

For example. I have code field in my model, and there is few elements with code "XXX", few with code "YYY", few with "ZZZ", etc. And I have a list which contains -for example- ['XXX', 'YYY'] And I need to get records with code XXX and YYY from db.

I have no idea when I can start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django filter with list of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letsay you have a model in Django for storing cars your garage has.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufactirer = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    make = models.DatetimeField()
    anotherfield = ......
```

Now to filter these cars by name of manufacturer, you can do :

```
Car.objects.filter(manufacturer='BMW')
```

In case you you want to filter cars by all german makers you can do something like this :

```
manufacturer_list = ['BMW', 'VW', 'AUDI']
Car.objects.filter(manufacturer__in=manufacturer_list)
```

This is the SQL equivalent of

```
SELECT ... WHERE manufacturer IN ('BMW', 'VW', 'AUDI');
```

You can also use a queryset to dynamically fetch the list of values first. This is valuable in the case of when manufacturers list comes from a django query.

```
manufacturer_list = Manufacturer.objects.filter(name__contains='mer')
cars = Car.objects.filter(manufacturer__in=manufacturer_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your list:

```
lst = ['XXX', 'YYY']
```

Now you can filter like:

```
elements = Model.objects.filter(code__in=lst)
```