# Django filter against list with and

Tags: django, filter, django-views, django-queryset

So what im trying to do is filtering against a list that comes from the queries and returning the possible options.

I got three models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)

class Colors(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now what I want to do is following:

- Get all Posts where is_active == True
- Get all Posts where colors are contained in queries
- Get all Posts where category is same as the one in query

My attempt looks like this:

```
# to be able using multiple values like ?color=red&color=blue&color=yellow
queryparams = dict(request.query_params.lists()) 

colors_list = []
categories_list = []

if 'color' in query_params:
    colors_list = query_params['color']

if 'category' in query_params:
    categories_list = query_params['category']

posts = Post.objects.filter(is_active=True)

if colors_list:
    for color in colors_list:
        posts = posts.filter(colors__title=color)

if categories_list:
    for category in categories_list:
        posts = posts.filter(category__title=category)

colors_options = posts.order_by('colors__title').values_list('colors__title', flat=True).distinct()
categories_options = posts.order_by('category__title').values_list('category__title', flat=True).distinct()
```

The options part currently doesnt work how I would like it to do. Lets say I got 5 objects with following colors:

1. black, blue, white, yellow
2. black
3. blue, red, white
4. red, white, yellow
5. black, yellow

If I would search with ?color=red&color=white it should give me following options:

1. black, blue, white, yellow
2. black
3. *blue, **red**, **white***
4. ***red***, **white**, yellow
5. black, yellow

blue, red, white, yellow but it only returns one color

Is there also more efficient and idiomatic way to achieve this?
This is just a snippet, in real there are way more options but im trying to keep it clear here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
if colors_list:
    for color in colors_list:
        posts = posts.filter(colors__title=color)
```

Try to do:

```
if colors_list:
    posts = posts.filter(colors__title__in=colors_list)
```

Please see: [django filter with list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values)

Comment: This would cause an OR filter. I need a AND.
Meaning that the field needs to contain all values of the list.