# use django_filters to filter for multiple arguments

Tags: django, graphql, relayjs, graphene-python, django-filters

I am using Relay, Django, Graphene Graphql.

I would like to **use django_filters to filter for multiple arguments** of type on accommodation. This is described in my schema file and atm looks like:

```
class AccommodationNode(DjangoObjectType) :
    class Meta:
        model = Accommodation
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = ['type']
```

This works perfectly if I pass a single string like: `{"accommodationType": "apartment"}`, but what if **I want to filter for all accommodations that are apartments OR hotels**? something like: `{"accommodationType": ["apartment","hotel"]}`

This is my model:

```
class Accommodation(models.Model):
    ACCOMMODATION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('apartment', 'Apartment'),
        ('host_family', 'Host Family'),
        ('residence', 'Residence'),
    )
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='accommodations')
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        choices=ACCOMMODATION_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='apartment'
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.school) + " - " + self.type
```

Is there any way I can do this without writing custom filters as are suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values)? For only one filter field this is a great solution but I'll end up having around 50 throughout my application including linked objects...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Django REST Framework Filters:

https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters

It supports more than exact matches, like `in`, which you are looking for, but also `exact`, `startswith`, and many more, in the same style of Django's ORM. I use it frequently and have been impressed - it even integrates with DRF's web browseable API. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Will give a bit more explanation in a answer myself :)

Answer (score 2):

like FlipperPA mentioned, I need to use 'in'. According to the django_filter docs:

> ‘in’ lookups return a filter derived from the CSV-based BaseInFilter.

and an example of BaseInFilter in the [docs](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter):

```
class NumberRangeFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass

class F(FilterSet):
    id__range = NumberRangeFilter(name='id', lookup_expr='range')

    class Meta:
        model = User

User.objects.create(username='alex')
User.objects.create(username='jacob')
User.objects.create(username='aaron')
User.objects.create(username='carl')

# Range: User with IDs between 1 and 3.
f = F({'id__range': '1,3'})
assert len(f.qs) == 3
```

The answer to my question:

```
class AccommodationNode(DjangoObjectType) :
    class Meta:
        model = Accommodation
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = {
            'type': ['in']
            }
```

With the argument `{"accommodationType": "apartment,hotel"}` will work