# Apply OR logic on Q objects query in a list

Tags: python, sql, django

I am looking to apply an OR query on a list of elements in `expertiseParams`

My code is :

```
queryset_list = Profile.objects.all()

for expertise in expertiseParams:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(Q(expertisematch__expertise=expertise))
```

My question is : how can I implement an OR logic on all the Q objects filtered?
Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for `filter(expertisematch__expertise__in=expertiseParams)`?

Comment: no, I am looking to perform an OR logic on all the qeries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django filter with list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/django-filter-with-list-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sayse!

Answer is this:

```
queryset_list = Profile.objects.all()
queryset_list =queryset_list.filter(expertisematch__expertise__in=expertiseParams)
```