# Django filter exact value in list

Tags: django

Good day again SO. I was hoping you can help me with some of the logic.

Based on this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9304968), I can filter the search with a list which works perfectly. However, I wish to get an EXACT id instead of at least one matches.

models:

```
class Condition:
  condition_name = models.CharField(....)

class Jobs:
  jobs = models.CharField(...)

class JobsConditions:
  account = models.ForeignKey(Account...)
  job_item = models.ForeignKey(Jobs...)
  condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition...)
```

So if I try to search for Jobs with Conditions, I do the following:

```
  cond_array = [1,2,4,5] # Append to array based on request.
  condition_obj = Condition.objects.filter(id__in=cond_array)
```

Then compare `condition_obj` to `JobsConditions` model. How to use this so that I will only `get` only the jobs with exact condition? No more no less.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wanting something like this:

1. Filter `JobsConditions` by `condition__id` and get the associated `job_item__jobs` as a list:

```py
jobs_list = (JobsConditions.objects
    .filter(condition__id__in=cond_array)
    .values_list('job_item__jobs', flat=True))
```

2. Filter `Jobs` by that `jobs_list`:

```py
jobs = Jobs.objects.filter(jobs__in=jobs_list)
```

Comment: Also add this `Jobs.objects.filter(jobsconditions_set__id__in=cond_array)`. One can traverse over relations using `__` in a query.