# Django how to search for one Model based on multiple foreign keys?

Tags: python, django

I'm essentially trying to build a filter based on the model's name and multiple foreign keys.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Foo can have the same names, but different Bars.

I want to search for the specific Foo based on Bars.

So far I am able to parse user input and create a list ["foo.name", "bar.name", "bar.name"]

How do I filter the product based on that specific Foo? and with trailing Bars?

```
# pseudocode process
foo = foo.objects.filter(name__contains=list[0] and foo.objects.filter(bar_name__in=[list]
```

Comment: Is it what you're trying to ask for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/how-can-i-filter-a-django-query-with-a-list-of-values

Comment: @sudden_appearance Mmm sort of but it needs to be in combination with the first parameter.

Comment: you can just separate by comma that AND's filters and i guess that's all you need

Comment: so `foo.objects.filter(name__contains=list[0], bar__name__in=[list])` should be what you want

Comment: @sudden_appearance so this works now, the issue was the ```and``` I had to use ```&```, apparently according to another post - there's this whole thing with how querysets are returned in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe if you give a related_name to the ForeignKey, you should be able to search from Foo using that as the field.

So if you do `models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="backlink")`, then Foo would have a backlink field you could search on.

Have a look here and see if that helps.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: There's no issues with the backlink, it's the issue with the contains and in functions. It's returning an empty query set when I put ```and```

Comment: issue was with the ```and``` had to use ```&``` due to how querysets are returned in Django