# Django queryset icontains filter but "vise versa"

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I have a Model:

```
class Sources(models.Model):
    ...
    vendor = models.CharField(max_value=128, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

And for example some data:

```
select id, vendor from "webgui_sources";
 id |       vendor
----+-----------------
  6 | oracle
  5 | microsoft
```

Then I have a string like "oracle;microsoft;apache" and I need to check are there models where `vendor` value is included to this string. So basically I need to collect all vendors which `vendor` value is included to "oracle;microsoft;apache".

Whereas

```py
Sources.objects.filter(vendor__icontains='oracle;microsoft;apache')
```

produces the following SQL-query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "webgui_sources" WHERE UPPER("webgui_sources".vendor) LIKE UPPER('oracle;microsoft;apache')
```

I need to swap the fields and get something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "webgui_sources" WHERE UPPER('oracle;microsoft;apache') LIKE UPPER("webgui_sources".vendor)
```

I tried to use `extra` and it did the job, but since using `extra` is not advised I tried to create custom lookup:

```py
class IContainsReverse(PatternLookup):     
     lookup_name = "icontains_reverse"      

     def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):         
          lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)         
          params.extend([self.rhs])         
          return "%s ~* {}".format(lhs_sql), params    

Field.register_lookup(IContainsReverse)
```

This `lookup` allows me to produce a query like this:

```py
Sources.objects.filter(vendor__icontains_reverse='oracle;microsoft;apache')
```

```sql
select * from "webgui_sources" where 'oracle;microsoft;apache' ~* "webgui_sources".vendor;
```

More or less it works but it looks clunky and works only with PostgreSQL. I hope that  there is a more Django-way solution to do that, could somebody advice any more Django-way alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I filter a Django query with a list of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304908/how-can-i-filter-a-django-query-with-a-list-of-values)

Comment: @IvanStarostin: this will not work since we need case-insensitive matching here, and the `__in` matches exaclty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the value with an [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) for the expression, and then [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) on that alias:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

Sources.objects.alias(filter_value=Value('oracle;microsoft;apache')).filter(
    filter_value_icontains=F('vendor')
)
```

that being said, you can make a query that works with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

vals = 'oracle;microsoft;apache'
Sources.objects.filter(
    *[Q(vendor__iexact=v) for v in vals.split(';')], _connector=Q.OR
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! It produces a little bit clunky SQL like REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(("webgui_sources"."vendor"), E'\\', E'\\\\'), E'%', E'\\%'), E'_', E'\\_')) but this is required, I understand.

Comment: @Andrey: well `icontains` means it transforms it to `foo LIKE %bar%, but if `bar` contains percentages for example, these need to be escaped, otherwise these are interpreted as wildcards. So if you would use `or%cle` instead, you don't want to work with `LIKE %or%cle%`, but `LIKE %or\%cle%`.