# How to get a record from database which is matching to list of values?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a list which contains the employee ids. now I want to compare values containing in the list with the database and need to retrieve the record from the database which is matching with list ids

I have written this code which getting the employee's id from the database and stores these values in the list. 
`employees_list =   Employee.objects.values_list('employeeid', flat=True)`

Now I want to fetch records from another database which contains this id. 
Now I am writing following query but it is not retrieving this record.

`employees_list = ActualSheet.objects.filter(employeeid__contains= employees_list).values()`

it must fetch the record but it is not fetching any record

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a django queryset using an array on a field like SQL's "IN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016794/how-to-filter-a-django-queryset-using-an-array-on-a-field-like-sqls-in)

Comment: See also the available [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/lookups/).